# Как сделать текст единым из скобок в Python 3

Tags: строки, индексы, range, кортежи

Я работаю с телеграмм-ботом. Хотя это не сильно важно.
`message.text =` это как `input()`
`respend =` это значение температуры (например: ***22***°C)

1 api - переводит с русского на английский для 2 api (2 - openweathermap)

Потом я получаю кортеж - например такой `("На данный момент температура города ", message.text, " составляет ", respend, "°C")`

Вот мой код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["mweather"])
def translate(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши город на русском языке')
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
    def start(message):
        TEXT_TO_TEXT_URL = "https://fasttranslator.herokuapp.com/api/v1/text/to/text"
        LANG = "ru-en"
        TEXT = message.text
        url = f"{TEXT_TO_TEXT_URL}?source={TEXT}&lang={LANG}"
        resp = requests.get(url).json()
        TEXT_TO_TEXT_URL1 = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather"
        APPID1 = "feafbc02a888d27599aa924ae7a72073"
        TEXT1 = resp["data"]
        url = f"{TEXT_TO_TEXT_URL1}?q={TEXT1}&appid={APPID1}"
        resp = requests.get(url).json()
        d1 = 9 / 5
        resp1 = resp['main']["temp_max"] * d1
        resp2 = resp1 - 459.67
        resp1 = resp2 - 32
        resp1 = resp1 * 5
        resp1 = resp1 / 9
        respend = round(resp1)
        wresult = "На данный момент температура города ", message.text, " составляет ", respend, "°C"
        print(wresult[0][1][2][3][4])
```

Все нужные модули импортировал, а ошибка такова:

```
print(wresult[0][1][2][3][4])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Но вроде в кортеже `("На данный момент температура города ", message.text, " составляет ", respend, "°C")` все нормально - как раз подходит под индексы! Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment:  wresult[0][1][2][3][4] - это один элемент 5-мерного списка, а не пять элементов одномерного

Comment: Вы что хотите получить то на выходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что мешает использовать [f-строки](https://shultais.education/blog/python-f-strings), которые как раз позволяют вставлять в строку различные переменных любых типов безо всяких танцев с кортежами?

```py
wresult = f"На данный момент температура города {message.text} составляет {respend} °C"
```